# Community Wiki response only Questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

**Community Wiki response only Questions?**

I may have to test the waters here, but I would like to try and set up a few community wiki response only questions on the Great Outdoors.

I set one such question on [Beer, Wine & Spirits SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/) and one answer on [Christianity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) with some success. I find it a great way to get one single answer to a question that would normally too broad:

[What cocktails are named, created or in some other sense may be used by Catholics to celebrate their liturgical year?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/7632/5064)

[How do Catholics observe Lent through a dignified and appropriate use of food?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/68138/how-do-catholics-observe-lent-through-a-dignified-and-appropriate-use-of-food)

Seeing that this may be a rather broad question, I desire to set up the answer as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post.

> Community Wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community. They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not contribute to any user's reputation. - [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I am hoping that this would generate even more interest on The Great Outdoors.

I hope this will be set an model to others to create their own questions that could be answered in such as way, because they would normally be too broad.

Reputation is not attributed to an individual in a Community Wiki answer.

If this question is looked on in a negative light, I am good with that for at lest I can see how the site would like to progress!

**An example question:**

**What foraging plants have been used historically by people that that are named after Christian themes such as saints and biblical traditions.** (Various languages use common names to identify plants and many times there is an historical legend that leads to a biblical story or something about such plants in the life of a particular saint). Foraging food stuffs in the wild was much more earnestly done in the Middle Ages.

Comment: Two observations, looking at your question on christianity it is clear, that there is no option for answers to be limited to the one community answer, people can still add stand alone answers on their own.  You have not posted a main space example question, and each question must stand on it's own so not sure your meta question can be answered. Lastly here is a different approach [on Pets.se where multiple users provide answer support AND get rep](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18810/13)

Comment: Ken - can I ask you for a couple of example questions. I am unsure what types would work well here, especially as SE's official position is to try to dissuade CW.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the Community Wiki questions it's with the execution.

["Official" providers of topographic maps per country](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19254/official-providers-of-topographic-maps-per-country) , [What is the warning call for falling rocks in your area?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15817/what-is-the-warning-call-for-falling-rocks-in-your-area)  are great examples of where one wiki answer made sense because rather than many answers it's all in one place.

[Where in Europe is wild camping permitted?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/96/where-in-europe-is-wild-camping-permitted/) is an example of a question that should have been a wiki, but rather people posted repeating answers.

The problem is that just because it's a wiki, doesn't mean people won't rush past and post their own and it doesn't seem like the community wants to enforce it .

For example
[What are some mortal dangers in temperate woods?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/what-are-some-mortal-dangers-in-temperate-woods)